# Abrir um aplicativo android quando uma página web for aberta

Tags: android

Olá, tenho um aplicativo de mídia indoor que roda em ambiente android este aplicativo fica aberto para 24h por dia, porem preciso fechar este aplicativo uma ou duas vesses por dia, para isso preciso de um script que posso programar para abrir em um determinado horário via página web, isso seria possível?

```
osascript -e 'quit app "APP"'
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar app links para isso, é a abordaremos mais adequada, porém você vai ter que fazer uma série de configurações. Uma outra opção mais simples é usar deeplink.

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).